# Sort names in a list by order of importance

Tags: python, sorting

I have multiple list which is arranged by order of importance. I need to do sorting on this list. Important thing is that the last name in the list is important. If there is two similar name as the last name in the list then the last name should be printed first. Also I need to make sure that alphabets case do not change after sorting.

```
>>> mylist = ["Ramesh G","K V R Santhosh","Srikanth T G", "R V Laxaman","Ramesh Ghosh"]

>>> mylist.sort()

>>> for x in sorted(mylist):

...     print x

...

K V R Santhosh
R V Laxaman
Ramesh G
Ramesh Ghosh
Srikanth T G
```

In the above sorting I am getting "Ramesh G" printed first, and my requirement is to print "Ramesh Ghosh" Before "Ramesh G" as below :

```
K V R Santhosh
R V Laxaman
Ramesh Ghosh
Ramesh G
Srikanth T G
```

Thank you

---

I have manged to write the code to sort the name by last name but still not able to find out how to print the last name before any similar name in the list after sort.

```
#!/bin/python
# sort a list of names by last name

import operator

data = input ("Enter the list: ")

data_as_lists = [ line.split() for line in data ]

data_as_lists.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(-1))

for each_item in data_as_lists :
   print " ".join(each_item)
```

This code prints the output as below :

```
python sort_name.py
Enter the list: ["Ramesh G","K V R Santhosh","Srikanth T G", "R V Laxaman","Ramesh Ghosh"]
Ramesh G
Srikanth T G
Ramesh Ghosh
R V Laxaman
K V R Santhosh
```

The desired output which I want should be like this:

```
 python sort_name.py
    Enter the list: ["Ramesh G","K V R Santhosh","Srikanth T G", "R V Laxaman","Ramesh Ghosh"]
    Ramesh Ghosh
    Ramesh G
    Srikanth T G
    R V Laxaman
    K V R Santhosh
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.x you can pass a `cmp` paramter to `list.sort` method, where you can implement any custom compare function e.g.

```
def mycmp(a, b):
    if a.startswith(b):
        return -1
    return cmp(a, b)

mylist = ["Ramesh G","K V R Santhosh","Srikanth T G", "R V Laxaman","Ramesh Ghosh"]
mylist.sort(cmp=mycmp)
print "\n".join(mylist)
```

Output:

```
K V R Santhosh
R V Laxaman
Ramesh Ghosh
Ramesh G
Srikanth T G
```

In python 3.x `cmp` argument has been removed, but you can use [`cmp_to_key`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) defined in func tools

Comment: Thanks for your input 

In below case it fails to print the result as per the requirement.






    >>> mylist = ["Alan","aLan","alAn","alaN","ALan","AlAn","AlaN","aLAn","aLaN","alAN"]
    >>> mylist.sort(cmp=mycmp)
    >>> print "\n".join(mylist)
    ALan
    AlAn
    AlaN
    Alan
    aLAn
    aLaN
    aLan
    alAN
    alAn
    alaN

The desired output should be like this :

    [ "alAN",  "aLaN",  "aLAn",  "AlaN",  "AlAn",  "ALan",  "alaN",  "alAn",  "aLan",  "Alan" ]

Comment: @PratapSingh modify the cmp function according to your requirement, I have shown an example of how it could be done